# WordPress HTTPS (SSL) Permalink Configuration for Nginx

Tags: php, wordpress, ssl, nginx

I've installed Nginx, PHP-FPM,SSL certificate (Let's Encrypt), and WordPress 4.6.1 on my server and working well.
But, when I change the permalink settings to anything other than default,I get 404 errors on every post,article and page.
In my nginx config file I have the following code under my location / block :

> try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

Here is my nginx.conf:

```js
server {
    listen      xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80;
    server_name raharja.com www.raharja.com;
    root        /home/admin/web/raharja.com/public_html;
    index       index.php index.html index.htm;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/domains/raharja.com.log combined;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/domains/raharja.com.bytes bytes;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/domains/raharja.com.error.log error;

    location / {

  # WordPress permalinks configuration
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

        location ~* ^.+\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|bmp|ico|svg|css|js)$ {
            expires     max;
        }

        location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
                return  404;
            }

            fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9001;
            fastcgi_index   index.php;
            include         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }
    }

    error_page  403 /error/404.html;
    error_page  404 /error/404.html;
    error_page  500 502 503 504 /error/50x.html;

    location /error/ {
        alias   /home/admin/web/raharja.com/document_errors/;
    }

    location ~* "/\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$" {
        deny    all;
        return  404;

    }

    include     /etc/nginx/conf.d/phpmyadmin.inc*;
    include     /etc/nginx/conf.d/phppgadmin.inc*;
    include     /etc/nginx/conf.d/webmail.inc*;

    include     /home/admin/conf/web/nginx.raharja.com.conf*;
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I suggesting you try this:

```
 if (!-e $request_filename)
    {
       rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
    }
```

Comment: still receive a 404

Comment: Where you have option for SSL?